# Cloudfront: setting s3 path difference from Origin

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, cdn, amazon-cloudfront

Cache behaviour setting, i use

```
s3/*
```

to redirect request to s3 folder, but i don't want to place my images under a folder named s3 but right under s3 bucket to redirect like this:

```
xxxx.cloudfront.com/s3/images/1.png  -> bucket_name/images/1.png
```

not

```
xxxx.cloudfront.com/s3/images/1.png  -> bucket_name/s3/images/1.png
```

Please help to show me how to config like this.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I don't think this is possible. An Origin Path can redirect to a subdirectory, (eg `index.htm` -> `production/index.htm`) but CloudFront can't strip out path portions.

See documentation: [Origin Path](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/distribution-web-values-specify.html#DownloadDistValuesOriginPath)

Some options:

- Use a separate distribution instead of prefixing paths with `s3`
- Just put `s3/` at the front of your filenames (and actually use the full path)

Answer (score 18):

You can do this [with lambdas](https://linuxacademy.com/howtoguides/posts/show/topic/19955-url-rewriting-in-aws-cloudfront) here's the relevant lambda snippet.

```
exports.handler = (event, context, callback) => {
    // this is the request we want to re-map
    var request = event.Records[0].cf.request;

    // the request has a 'uri' property which is the value we want to overwrite
    // rewrite the url applying your custom logic
    request.uri = 'some custom logic here to rewrite the url';    

    // quit the lambda and let the request chain continue
    callback( null, request );    
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately this is not possible.  Cloudfront will map the exact request path back to the origin.  The only option it provides for manipulating the origin path is to add a prefix - it does not permit removing anything from the path.

[Origin Path](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/distribution-web-values-specify.html#DownloadDistValuesOriginPath) has details on the Origin path setting - but you'll see from that page there is no option to remove any part of the Request Path.